# Help in reopening a question marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

The following question was recently marked as a duplicate.  However the comments associated with the question clearly point out why this question is not identical to what it is marked as.

[GCC optimization to reduce target ram usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862466/gcc-optimization-to-reduce-target-ram-usage)

I am neither the OP nor a 3k user, so the standard tools are not available to me.  This is in a less-frequented portion of SO and it seems unlikely to garner views + flags from 5 3k users to get it reopened.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I voted for reopen. I assume more will follow because you have a valid point (without being an GCC expert)

Comment: Thanks for the help all, it's been reopened.  I'll work on helping the OP improve the question overall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have sufficient reputation, you can vote to reopen.

If you don't, you can edit the question to help clarify why the proposed duplicate is not in fact a duplicate of the question.  (While you can be explicit about this, you can also be implicit and simply emphasize or clarify the points that were confusing enough to result in the closure to begin with.)  *Usually* there is some reason a question is closed as a duplicate.  Even if it's not a duplicate, there is often some point that is vague, unclear, or simply buried too deep in the post for the readers to realize why the question isn't a duplicate.  Editing the post to help clarify this, especially if you don't mention the duplicate, or the closure, explicitly, can really improve a question.

Both actions, either voting to reopen or editing, will put the question in the reopen review queue, which will give it enough attention by 3k+ users to determine if it should be reopened or not.

You don't need to make a meta post for every single question you see that you think should be reopened.  You should generally reserve such attention for particularly controversial posts in which it's unclear if a question should or should not be reopened, or questions that are being repeatedly reopened and closed due to disagreement among users.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll figure out if there's a way to edit the question to clarify the nuances.  It's a fairly weak question overall but is worth keeping around, imho.